# MVC 4 bundled scripts does not reflect my changes to the script files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a MVC 4 application in .NET 4.0. My web hosting provider (network solutions) has virtual directories setup so I can't use the default bundling behavior (I think).

In my _Layout view I have this line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dd-d2")
```

In BundleConfig.cs I have

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dd-d2").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/dd-d2.js"));
```

And everything works fine when I run in visual studio. But when i upload to my web hosting, The file is not found because it appends the virtual folder in front of the bundle path.
instead of `/bundles/dd-d2?v=BlahBlah`, I get `/ROOT_FOLDER/bundles/dd-d2?v=BlahBlah`

I fixed this issue by adding this to my line in the _Layout file

```
@Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/dd-d2"))
```

The Url.Content helper converts the virtual path into an app absolute path and it finds my bundled script files.

Now, the problem I am having with that approach is, if I make a change to the javascript file, it is NOT reflected in the outputted bundled script file. It always has the old information in it even when I upload it to my web hosting. Is this file cached somewhere? Is there a better way of doing this? I would like to take advantage of the minification of my script files by using bundling.

if I do it this way, it does work

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dd-d2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But then my script is not minified.

Comment: Excellent Question. Did you ever find an answer?
Although, 4 years old, this question is still relevant. In VS 2013, I still have this issue. The "v=" value does not change

Comment: I switched from network solutions to GoDaddy and I didn't have a problem. But no, I never found a fix to this exact problem.